# Display image from local driver on Jsp Spring

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm creating a maven project, and i try to display image from my computer but JSP do not allow it.
So after search on Stackoverflow i got a solution is using FileServlet to handle it,
but after try it, i still can not get image to display, so please help me

this is my code:

FileServlet.java

```
package fileServer;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
  private String filePath;

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
  */
  public FileServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  }

 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
  *      response)
  */
 public void init() throws ServletException {

   // Define base path somehow. You can define it as init-param of the
   // servlet.
   this.filePath = "F:\\DrugStore\\Medicine";

   // In a Windows environment with the Applicationserver running on the
   // c: volume, the above path is exactly the same as "c:\files".
   // In UNIX, it is just straightforward "/files".
 }

 protected final void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
   HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

   System.out.println("In do get");

   // Get requested file by path info.
   String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();

   // Check if file is actually supplied to the request URI.
   if (requestedFile == null) {
     // Do your thing if the file is not supplied to the request URI.
     // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or
     // just ignore it.
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
     return;
   }

   // Decode the file name (might contain spaces and on) and prepare file
   // object.
   File file = new File(filePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));

   // Check if file actually exists in filesystem.
   if (!file.exists()) {
     // Do your thing if the file appears to be non-existing.
     // Throw an exception, or send 404, or show default/warning page, or
     // just ignore it.
     response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND); // 404.
     return;
   }

   // Get content type by filename.
   String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

   // If content type is unknown, then set the default value.
   // For all content types, see:
   // http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp
   // To add new content types, add new mime-mapping entry in web.xml.
   if (contentType == null) {
     contentType = "application/octet-stream";
   }

   // Init servlet response.
   response.reset();
   response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
   response.setContentType(contentType);
   response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
   response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""
            + file.getName() + "\"");

   // Prepare streams.
   BufferedInputStream input = null;
   BufferedOutputStream output = null;

   try {
     // Open streams.
     input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
     output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(),
                DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

     // Write file contents to response.
     byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
     int length;
     while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
       output.write(buffer, 0, length);
     }
   } finally {
     // Gently close streams.
     close(output);
     close(input);
   }
 }

 protected final void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("In do post");

 }

 private static void close(Closeable resource) {
   if (resource != null) {
     try {
       resource.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
       // Do your thing with the exception. Print it, log it or mail
       // it.
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
}
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>fileServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>fileServer.FileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>fileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fileServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

index.jsp

```
<td colspan="2"><img src="fileServlet?path=${pr.imgname}" /></td>
```

thank for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not clearly know how you code is write,but I guess all your jsp page are in the **WEB-INF** folder,and can only be accessed via springMVC request.This is due to the spring dispatcher filter,in order to let the static resource to be exclude of the filter,you can add the static file type to the default servlet mapping as below:

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.bmp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes flyFox, all my jps page are under WEB-INF, thank for help,